MacOs terminal can't recognise any basic commands
Terminal can no longer recognise basic commandes such as ls, clear, etc...
Hi, i recently downloaded mysql on my macOs, then created a .zshrc file where i added the path for mysql.
However, terminal can no longer recognise any basic commands like clear, ls, etc.
When i run echo PATH, I get as a response that same path for mysql.
I re-opened the .zshrc file and deleted that export line i added earlier.
I added them temporarly by using `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin' and it works.
What i would like to know now, Is how to get back to default settings before messing the path, as well as having a working mysql server on my machine.
Thank you

What you want to do is APPEND the path where MySQL is installed (ex: /opt/mysql/bin) to your PATH variable:
PATH="$PATH:/opt/mysql/bin"

